# jQuery 3 - Show and Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `div`'s.

1. Has a *next* button
2. Has a *back* and a *next* button
3. Has a *back* and *submit* button

**jQuery**

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    //hide parent and show next
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
});

$('.back').click(function() {
   //hide parent and show previous
   $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();
});
```

The 2nd page just appears for a few milliseconds and then goes back to the first one.. is it deprecated?

Comment: Please post your HTML :)

Comment: Please provide HTML code. Thanks.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bao6h36r/

Comment: You could be submitting the page try to preventing the event, $('.next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().hide().next().show();//hide parent and show next
});

Comment: Thanks, thats working!

Comment: @PaulJohnDiwa it seems your comment was accepted by OP. Please post it as an answer so it can be accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be submitting the page try preventing the event.

```js
$('.next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
  //hide parent and show next 
});

  //your othe codes
```

Comment: thanks. how can I only go forward when a input isnt empty?